# How to calculate time elapsed since an action without the danger of the user changes the time

Tags: android, time

Hi i am developing an application and i want the user to be able to kill an enemy again after 12 hours have passed. How can i do this to avoid the possibility of the user changing the time in his phone and enabling again the option to kill an enemy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [sticky service](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/ForegroundService.html). Every time you kill an enemy, run a CountdownTimer.

However I think this is overkill, If it is a simple game that you are making, you should store the [elapsed time](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#elapsedRealtime%28%29) since boot. Then regenerate the enemy if the time difference is > 12 hours.